# How do I import multiple versions of the same crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

As discussed in [Is it documented that Cargo can download and bundle multiple versions of the same crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51714866/155423), it's possible for Cargo to pull in multiple versions of the same crate for a single program. How do I access both of these versions concurrently?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of [Rust 1.31](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.31.0/RELEASES.md#cargo), you can [rename dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html?highlight=rename,depende#renaming-dependencies-in-cargotoml) in Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
futures_01 = { package = "futures", version = "0.1.0" }
futures_03 = { package = "futures", version = "0.3.0" }
```

You can choose whatever name you want for the key. The `package` attribute needs to be the official name of the crate.

Within your code, you can access version 0.1.x using the crate name `futures_01`, and version 0.3.x via `futures_03`.

See also:

- [How to idiomatically alias a crate in Rust 2018?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50999616/155423)
- [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423)

Comment: Is it possible to do this before Rust 1.31?

Comment: Just so others don't waste their time trying, this only works if the major versions are different. Different minor versions with the same major version (like "~1.2" and "~1.3" or "=0.6.0" and "=0.6.5") are fundamentally incompatible with cargo.