# How to have two difference patch versions of the same package?

Tags: rust

I depend on a (critical) package that releases breaking changes on patch releases (swc). I just installed a third party dependency that also depends on the same package (deno_runtime).

deno_runtime uses an older version of swc than my main project and I can't downgrade the whole project to it. Cargo complains that `all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.`

I'm using `"=0.33.19"` and deno_runtime is using `"=0.33.18"` (there are enough breaking changes between the releases that I cannot downgrade to `.18`.

I tried renaming `swc_common` by editing my Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
internal_swc_common = { package = "swc_common", version = "=0.33.19" }
```

But Cargo still installs my version over the top of deno_runtimes (probably because it's a patch version)

I raised a PR in Deno's repo to bump their swc version, but in the meantime, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Not really. In order to use a crate with different versions, they have to differ in the 'major' part of the version number.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate. I guess I could fork swc, republish it and consume the fork

Comment: You wouldn't have to publish it, just use  the fork locally with an increased version number to 1.x and combine both in a Cargo workspace setup.

Comment: Yes, please avoid needlessly republishing a fork, and instead use e.g. a git dependency, e.g. `foo = { git = "https://github.com/user/foo" }`

Comment: The real problem behind this, however, is swc not sticking to semantic versioning. A breaking change while still unstable (<1.0) should result in an increase of the 'minor' part of the version number.

Comment: @vallentin Do git installations work with packages nested within workspaces?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739075/how-do-i-import-multiple-versions-of-the-same-crate should work... maybe try do cargo lock before

Comment: @Stargateur, I just tried this however it doesn't work unfortunately. Cargo still combines the packages

Comment: Apparently it only works for major versions unfortunately

Comment: Left an answer on the post describing how I resolved this collision

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a crate with different versions, they have to differ in the 'major' part of the version number. Since this is not the case here, you will have to use a workaround.

Create a Cargo workspace project containing your project and a local clone of the newer swc. You don't need to fork swc for that, but you could, of course. Then you will have to increase the version number in swc's Cargo.toml to 1.x.

In your projects Cargo.toml, refer to the local clone with a relative path and the new version number. Furthermore, you need to give the clone a new name. The entry would look like this:

> swc_new = { package=swc, version=1.x, path=../path_to_clone }

In your code, use swc_new instead of swc.

Comment: As cargo considers the first *nonzero* part of the version number as major you could instead use `0.34` here which one is more likely to clash with actual versions I don't know.

Comment: Ah, good to know! But 1.x would still be safe here.

Comment: swc is organizes their packages within a cargo workspace, would this approach work given the references between packages are coordinated by the workspace Cargo.toml? I was considering doing this but vendoring in swc as a git submodule

Comment: A git submodule is a good idea. I do not know if you can nest workspaces.

Comment: If it doesn't work, I would ask swc to republish 0.33.18 as 0.34.0 and yank 0.33.18 from crates.io. It's a reasonable request imo.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was [creating a (messy) script](https://github.com/alshdavid/mach/blob/main/scripts/swc_setup.ts) that downloads the swc repo as an archive and [vendors it into my current project](https://github.com/alshdavid/mach/tree/main/vendor/swc).

It rewrites name and versions so there won't be conflicts.

Of course it didn't go that smoothly, swc is compiled with the nightly toolchain and Cargo does not support nested workspaces - but it looks like it compiles just fine.

Luckily there were no references [like these](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/main/cli/Cargo.toml#L56) otherwise I'd need to resolve them using the script - also the swc workspace contains all of the swc packages.

I can re-run the script to update SWC, it will pull from the latest `main` in github.

The benefit is that I will have a unique namespaced copy of swc that cannot have conflicts with any future third party libraries. The downside is that it's an annoying solution.